# Existing internal topic has invalid partitions

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When starting our Kafka Streams application in a test setup with just one Kafka broker we see the following error roughly 1 out of 15 runs:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Existing internal topic alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition has invalid partitions: expected: 32; actual: 12. Use 'kafka.tools.StreamsResetter' tool to clean up invalid topics before processing.
```

When we see the error above the actual number of partitions vary (expected is 32, actual is above 0 and below 32).

We are executing `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams#cleanUp` before calling `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams#start`. The Kafka broker is started without data (using https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/) for every test run.

When looking at the log for the Kafka broker we see the following:

```
2018-10-22 18:41:31,373] INFO Topic creation Map(
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-19 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-22 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-0 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-7 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-23 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-1 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-24 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-2 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-30 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-5 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-21 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-8 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-14 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-15 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-6 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-16 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-31 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-25 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-9 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-20 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-29 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-13 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-26 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-17 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-4 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-10 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-3 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-11 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-12 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-28 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-27 -> ArrayBuffer(42),
    alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition-18 -> ArrayBuffer(42)
) (kafka.zk.AdminZkClient)
```

It looks like the topic is created with the expected number of partitions (32). Later, in the same log, it looks like there is a request to create the topic again. We don't know why that happens but at least the request still contains the expected number of partitions (32):

```
[2018-10-22 18:43:29,851] INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 42]: Error processing create topic request for topic alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition with arguments (numPartitions=32, replicationFactor=1, replicasAssignments={}, configs={cleanup.policy=delete, segment.bytes=52428800, segment.ms=600000, retention.ms=9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes=52428800}) (kafka.server.AdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'alarm-message-streams-by-organization-repartition' already exists.
```

We have never seen this happen in non-test where we are running with 6 Kafka brokers. However, we are running a significantly higher number of test runs than deploys to non-test.

Note: It is not always the same topic that is causing the error.

The error is causing flakiness in our test setup so we would like to understand why it happens and deal with it. Can anybody provide some insights into this Kafka Streams behavior?

We are using Kafka and Kafka Streams 2.0.0.

Comment: I did find someone experiencing something that may be similar but it happened with an older Kafka Streams version and sounds like it was fixed: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201706.mbox/%3CCAB7X_oHi8PDew-m_=M-UYH_p0iPEThdwqeUaGhkJxmtuFzGAGA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Same here. 2.0.1.
Can i fix it with bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh?

Comment: Hi boriselec, if you have any more information please consider adding it to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7563

Answer (score 3):

It seems that incomplete/incorrect metadata is received from the Kafka cluster (ie your single broker). On startup (or to be more precise, in each rebalance), Kafka Streams check if internal topics exist with the expected number of partitions. If a topic does not exist, it's created (this should only happen once during the live time of an application). If it exists with the correct number of partitions, the topic is used. If the topic exists with incorrect number of partitions, the exception you report is thrown.

Calling `KafkaStreams#cleanup()` should not have any impact here. It's not the same as `StreamResetter` that you can call via `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` (cf. https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html)

I have no idea at the moment, what the root cause for the issue could be though, ie, why Kafka Streams received incorrect topic metadata. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, this helps to narrow down the focus to the Kafka broker since it sounds like the Kafka Streams application is reacting the way it is due to information from Kafka. So we will dig a bit more and then return with more information. Thanks for your input so far.

Comment: We tried using AdminClient to describe the topics when the Kafka Streams application got the StreamsException. AdminClient also reports that a topic has the wrong number of partitions! We don't understand it since the broker log seems to be fine. So, we need to figure out what is going on with the broker in our test setup. I'm accepting your answer. It didn't solve the problem but it did point out that Kafka Streams is not the issue here. Thank you.

Comment: We have a "fix" to reduce the flakiness now. When the Kafka Streams application fails with the exception, we can stop the application, stop the Kafka broker, start the Kafka broker, and finally start the application. Then the exception is not thrown. Of course this does not explain or fix the real issue at hand but it is still important because we all hate flaky tests.

Comment: Thanks for the details @MartinKampJensen. Not sure why this happens. In a single broker setup, async metadata propagation should not be an issue. Could you file a bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/issues/ Please include the description of the workaround. This might help to track down the issue.

Comment: I had this happen to me today.  Across multiple regions.  No changes to the topo.   Has the root cause of this ever been determined?