# After a redeploy, kafka streams complains that an Internal topic has invalid partitions. Why did this happen?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple topology that does some windowing on a topic.   I haven't made any changes to the topology nor do I set the partition size on any internal topic.

The only thing I did change was the number of stream threads (`NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG`) from 10 to 50.   Setting it back to 10 did not fix this.

```
 2021-10-07 22:48:24.452 ERROR : o.a.k.s.p.i.InternalTopicManager: stream-thread [main] 
Existing internal topic my-app-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000015-changelog 
has invalid partitions: expected: 10 ; actual: 1. 

Use 'kafka.tools.StreamsResetter' tool to clean up invalid topics before processing.
```

[From previous answers it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960918/356011) the way to fix this is to reset streams for the entire application (causing reprocessing from the beginning).   This isn't ideal.   I may try just deleting all the topics relating to this app and starting over.

My question - I would like to understand why this happened.   It seems like a pretty serious error without any visible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nor do I set the partition size on any internal topic

That's why you're getting an error. Increasing threads requires a higher partition count, since you can't have more `consumer threads * instances` than total partitions. The default is only one partition.

You also cannot decrease a topics partition count, without deleting the topic and recreating it, which is what the reset command does; it doesn't delete "user topics" that still have data in them, only resets the group id and deletes the internal topics

You don't need to reset the app since you can use `kafka-topics` and `kafka-reassign-partitions` CLI tools to add partitions manually

Comment: So increasing the thread count to 50 caused this?

Comment: In order to use more threads that aren't idle, more partitions need added, yes

Comment: Ok, thank you.  External topic partitions can be increased in size without having to delete the topic.   I guess there's some limitation in internal topics that prevents this?

Comment: Internal topic partition count gets assigned based on the input topic, IIRC. If you try to change it after the fact, you'll lose ordering